# How to debug iPhone app errors that occur before the first line

Tags: iphone, terminate

I have a fairly simple app.  It compiles fine.  Unfortunately, when I Build and Go, it fails before even the first line of code, thus making it impossible for me to even debug it.

Where do I start?  I do have the stack track though.[image]

Comment: Hnh. Up-voted, because that's interesting. And probably infuriating... =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the stack trace, it seems your Outlet connections seem messed up in your main XIB file - you could start looking there.

Other than that, you won't be able to *debug* much, because there's no source code for the iPhone built-in mechanisms, which seem to be failing here (most probably because of something you did in the interface designer/XIBs).

Comment: Your call is right on the money.  I renamed one of the outlets and forgot to make the matching changes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint at `objc_exception_throw`, then restart the application. The breakpoints should be kept after the restart, allowing you to see what's wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, he won't be able to see much, as all the code seems from `UIKit`...

Comment: Sometimes it's worth a try because exception throws tends to mess up the stack trace.

Comment: Where exactly is objc_exception_throw and how do I place a breakpoint there?

Comment: `objc_exception_throw` is called when some code `@throw` an `NSException` (or anything). You can set a breakpoint in the debug console (gdb) with `b objc_exception_throw`.

Comment: In the Breakpoints dialog, just go into global breakpoints, and double-click on a new line for a breakpoint - type in "objc_exception_throw" and you are all set.  I know you solved the problem but that's just helpful anyway.